# rendertarget texture not updated in unreal engine 5.1

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

i am using a scene capture component 2d and a static mesh in an overlay actor

the goal is to show the mesh on an umg widget via a render target texture and the corresponding material

it work first time .

but if i want to change the mesh with the “set mesh” function at run time the render target texture is not updated
actually it change the mesh on the 3d actor but the ui is not updated

i am not sure but it seems that there is a bug or a breaking change in the version i am using 5.1.1 because i have tested the same setup in version 4.27 and it worked just like expected

any idea on how to fix this please ?